How to ensure initial authentication with Azure AD in Angular app using guards and NGRX
I have an Angular application that's used internally within our intranet. The requirement is straightforward: users should be authenticated with Azure Active Directory as soon as they access any URL within the app. There's no need for a dedicated login or logout page. The authentication should be seamless and automatic. I am trying to achieve this by using the APP_INITIALIZER provider in the app.module. I was told that this is the first place in Angular projects that is executed. So ideal to trigger the login process:
app.module.ts:
export function initializeAuth(store: Store): Function {
  return () => store.dispatch(AuthActions.loginProcess());
}
//...
 providers: [
//...
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeAuth,
      deps: [Store],
      multi: true
    },
  ],

The effect, action, and selector look like this:
auth.actions:
export const loginProcess = createAction('[Auth] Login');
export const loginSuccess = createAction('[Auth] Login Success', props<{ user: User | null }>());
export const loginFailure = createAction('[Auth] Login Failure', props<{ error: any }>());

auth.effects:
loginStart$ = createEffect(() => {
      return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AuthActions.loginProcess),
        mergeMap(() => {
          return from(this.authService.initialize()).pipe(
            //filter(user => user !== null), removed this, because it caused an error
            map(user => AuthActions.loginSuccess({user})),
            catchError(error => of(AuthActions.loginFailure({error})))
          );
        })
      );
    }
  );

auth.selectors:
export const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<AuthState>('auth');

export const selectIsLoading = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (state: AuthState) => state.isLoading
);

export const selectUser = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (state: AuthState) => state.user
);

export const selectAuthError = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  (state: AuthState) => state.error
);

The behavior is as follows: if I include the filter mentioned in the effects comment to remove null values, the route times out after 30 seconds and does not work at all. If I remove the filter, I get flooded with null values. The selectUser returns null multiple times before the user is authenticated. But: As long as I am authenticated from Azure, so no redirection needed, there are no errors, and everything works fine even after a page refresh.
The problem arises when I am not yet authenticated and need to be redirected, e.g. first look at the page or cleaning the cache. Initially, the selectUser is null, causing the guard to redirect me back to the initial route ('/'). The simplest way would be to accept this redirection and redirect back to the intended URL after successful authentication.
The better practice, I believe, is to prevent the null spamming from the AuthService. I need to ensure that the AuthService only returns a user when fully authenticated, and does not emit null values. However, I am not sure how to achieve this. He needs to "wait" until I am authenticated
The Auth.service:
async initialize(): Promise<User | null> {
    if (this.isBrowser && this.msalInstance) {
      await this.msalInstance.initialize();
      const accounts = this.msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
      if (accounts.length > 0) {
        const tokenResponse = await this.msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
          account: accounts[0],
          scopes: ["user.read"]
        });
        if (tokenResponse) {
          return this.fetchUserFromApi(tokenResponse.accessToken);
        }
      }

      const response = await this.msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise();
      if (response && response.account) {
        return this.fetchUserFromApi(response.accessToken);
      } else {
        this.login();
        return null;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  async fetchUserFromApi(token: string): Promise<User> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').append('Token', `${token}`);
    const url = `https://localhost:7297/api/User/GetUser`;
    try {
      const response = await firstValueFrom(this.httpClient.get<User>(url, {headers: headers, withCredentials: true}));
      if (!response) {
        throw new Error('No user data returned from the API');
      }
      return response;
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error('Error fetching user from API:', error);
      throw new Error(`API Error: ${error.message || JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    }
  }

  login(): void {
    if (this.isBrowser && this.msalInstance) {
      this.msalInstance.loginRedirect({
        scopes: ['user.read']
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Login redirect failed', error);
      });
    }
  }

How cam I achieve one of the two possible solutions, or is there a better solution for my problem?

("users should be authenticated with Azure Active Directory as soon as they access any URL within the app.")
what do you mean by that can you explain it clearly.

you can see this in the code. ASAP The user enters the URL, he should be authenticated. There is no dedicated front end logic for the auth process. Its just initiate as soon as the user requests to access the page
